# Возможно ли в C# создать свой тип **значений**?

Tags: c#, unity3d, классы, типы-данных, int

Тип в C# - это, в целом, класс.

Типы делятся на [типы значения и ссылочные типы](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.16.php). Типами значений являются, например, int, double, float, bool... Типами же ссылочными являются, например, class, interface или - в Юнити - GameObject, Transform и т.д.

Так вот, если переменную типа значения можно присвоить сразу: `int a=3; bool b = false;`, то переменные ссылочных типов инициализируются при помощи слова new: `Cat cat = new Cat("Tom");`.

Я хочу создать свой тип для хранения больших чисел. Он будет представлять числа больше миллиона в экспоненциальном формате, например, `3.67 E8` - это `3.67*10^8`, т.е. `367000000`.

Сейчас у меня есть такой класс:

```
public class LargeInt {
      public string Number;
    
(1)   public LargeInt (string number) => Number = number;
}
```

Его я могу инициализировоать с помощью конструктора через слово new: `LargeInt price = new LargeInt("5 E10")`, т.е. это ссылочный тип.

**Возможно ли** сделать так, чтобы класс инициализировался прямо: `LargeInt price = "5 E10";`?

> Этот класс потом будет похож на обычный int. В нем будут функции ToString(), CompareTo(), операторы +,-... Потому что int не может работать с числами больше двух миллиардов с хвостиком.

Comment: `Тип в C# - это, в целом, класс` - не только класс.

Comment: Велосипед уже написан - [BigInteger](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8), он вообще безразмерный, у него нет предела в диапазоне чисел. По поводу значимых типов, тот же `int` - это структура, а не класс.

Comment: И да, `public string Number` хранение числа в строке - это выстрел себе в ногу, потому что строковые операции - самые медленные из всего что можно придумать для работы с числами.

Comment: @aepot Да, BIgInteger теоретически безразмерен, однако мне не нужноо хранить единицы и десятки, если число "квадрилионное". Про string согласен. Наверное, будет лучше хранить число отдельно в виде мантиссы (0-10) и порядка.

Comment: С мантиссой и порядком прекрасно справляется `double`.

Comment: `double d = 3.67E+8` поставьте курсор на `double` и нажмите F12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[User-defined conversion operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)

Как пример

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public string Val {get; private set;} 
    public static implicit operator MyClass(string d) {
        var ret = new MyClass();
        ret.Val = d;
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Использование

```
MyClass myclass = "some text";
Console.WriteLine(myclass.Val);
```

Вывод

```
some text
```

Comment: Спасибо. Это неявное преобразование строки в класс MyClass, верно?

Comment: да, `implicit` в определении переводится с английского как `неявный`.